# Run code if body does not have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

so im trying to execute a script only when the body has NOT the class "shifter-open". The "shifter-open"-class gets added to the body by this script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("body").addClass("shifter shifter-active");

    $('.shifter-handle').click( function() {         
        $("body").toggleClass("shifter-open");
        $(".scrollheader").toggleClass("hovered"); 
    });
});
```

My script which should only be executed when the body has NOT the class looks like this: (notice how i used if (!$("body"))

```
if (!$("body").hasClass("shifter-open")) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var $header = $(".scrollheader");
    $header.hover(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $header.addClass('hovered');
      }
    },function() {
      if ($header.hasClass('hovered')) {
        $header.removeClass('hovered');
      }
    });
    });
}
```

Comment: ...wait, so the class you're want to check for only gets added when `shifter-handle` is clicked? You don't know when that click will take place, so you won't know when to run it. You'll probably need to go ahead and bind the `hover` handlers and check for the class inside those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check inside the event handlers since the class can be toggled by user after page loads

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $header = $(".scrollheader");
  $header.hover(function() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("shifter-open") && $(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      $header.addClass('hovered');
    }
  }, function() {    
    if ($("body").hasClass("shifter-open")) {// no need to check if the hovered class exists
      $header.removeClass('hovered');
    }
  });
});
```